# how to remove double border around drop down

Tags: html, css, angular

**How do we remove the extra border around the *Rag Basic Type* drop down below?**

As you can see the following dropdown has an extra border around it:

[image]

Here's the relevant snippet of code:

```
  <div class="col">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="project-field-label" for="Rag Name">Rag Name</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="editRagColumns.RagName"
             name="RagName"
             type="text"
             class="form-control"
             id="RagName"
             aria-label="RagName"
             placeholder="{{ '@Configuration_EmailTemplate_Alias' | i18n }}"
             [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': RagName.invalid }"
             #RagName="ngModel"
             required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="project-field-label" for="RagBasicType">Rag Basic Type</label>
      <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="editRagColumns.BaseObjectType"
             name="RagBasicType"
             type="text"
             class="form-control"
             id="RagBasicType"
             [options]="baseObjectTypes"
             optionLabel="BaseObjectTypeName"

             [style]="{'width': '100%', 'border-color':'var(--dropdown-border-color)'}"
                  >
        </p-dropdown>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've tried the following:

`[style]="{'width':'100%', 'border-color':'transparent'}"`

However, then the height of Rag Name and Rag Basic Type fields are different:

[image]

Comment: did you try to remove `'border-color':'var(--dropdown-border-color)` ?

Comment: @ObadaSaada yes i did. gut shabbos !

Comment: try to change the value to transparent

Comment: @ObadaSaada do you mean like this? `'border-color':'transparent'`

Comment: please see updated question, i posted an image

Comment: check css files of p-dropdown to change the height

Comment: sorry, how i do i do that? im a beginner at this angular thig

Comment: you will find p-dropdown inside node_modules

Comment: try to add `p-0` to the second` col`   `<div class="col p-0">`  and see what happens

Comment: What are you getting if you inspect the html tree in your CSS are their any hints there as to where that extra border is coming from?

Comment: Have you tried removing border and outline by css?